# Segue to a ViewController from non-Storyboard ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

Im using Storyboard for most screens in my iPhone app. However, I have one screen in my storyboard where I dynamically load a XIB an embedded it within the main view. This XIB have an image and some text and is connected to its own UIViewController.
My problem is that when I tap on the image in the XIB I want to segue to another UIViewController in my Storyboard. However, because my XIB is not in my Storyboard (its dynamically added at runtime) there is no way I can connect my XIB's view controller with a segue. 
I'm getting the error **"Receiver () has no segue with identifier"**. This makes sense because the segue is not connected so is there anyway tha tI can programmatically segue to the other view?
I've seen examples where I can have a modal transition, but instead I would like to have a "push" transition.

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I really understand your question, but if you want a push transition, use this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```